# the run operation in debug mode stopped in android studio

Tags: android-studio

when i click run button in android studio it stopped debugging when the app start for just one project other project work normally , this happen when i try to update the gradle, and it dose not give me any error,
[when the app show the icon it stopped, but when i close the app and try to open from the phone with out the run button the app open and work normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdK1n.png).
any one can know what the issue?
i tried the "invalidate cash" and flutter clean and it dose not work